# Pandas dropping na within conditions

Tags: python, r, pandas, data.table

if i have the following input

```
participant trials Correct_Choice Opt_in  
1             1         NaN          1
1             1          1           NAN
2             1         NaN          1
2             1          0           NaN
```

My desired output is

```
participant trials Correct_Choice Opt_in  
1             1         1          1
2             1         0          1
```

What is the best way to do it in pands?

In R (using data.table) the code is as follows

```
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, na.omit) , by = list(participant,trials)]
```

For e.g.

e.g. data set in R

```
structure(list(participant = c("612550d21d30a44cb0d2d579", "612550d21d30a44cb0d2d579", 
"612550d21d30a44cb0d2d579", "612550d21d30a44cb0d2d579", "612550d21d30a44cb0d2d579", 
"612550d21d30a44cb0d2d579", "612550d21d30a44cb0d2d579", "612550d21d30a44cb0d2d579", 
"612550d21d30a44cb0d2d579", "612550d21d30a44cb0d2d579", "612550d21d30a44cb0d2d579", 
"612550d21d30a44cb0d2d579", "612550d21d30a44cb0d2d579", "612550d21d30a44cb0d2d579", 
"612550d21d30a44cb0d2d579", "612550d21d30a44cb0d2d579", "612550d21d30a44cb0d2d579", 
"612550d21d30a44cb0d2d579"), block = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), trials = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L), opt_in.keys = c(1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, 
NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA), correct_chosen = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, 
1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fd1a20102e0>)
```

Comment: All I can see in the resulting data.table for given data.table is your `NA` values are being replaced by `1`, is that what you want to achieve? Or, do you basically want to group the data.table by `participant` and `trials` and want to apply the function to get rid of `NA` values replacing it by 1?

Comment: the na values are being dropped, not by column or by row but by group-(participant and trials). So within each trial and within participant i aggregate the non na values

Comment: @user15791858 what do you mean by _aggregate_? Could you add the desired output to your code too?

Comment: Isn't that same as dropping `NA` values without any grouping? Look at [DataFrame.dropna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Comment: @B.ChristianKamgang He's printing the `structure` just copy the value starting from `list` all the way before `, row.names ` and pass it to `as.data.table` to create data.table out of it

Comment: @ThePyGuy I forgot the remove the `.internal.selfref ` attribute. thanks.

Comment: @user15791858 Not sure if it was intentional/expected but the result of your code contains lots of duplicates.

Comment: whats the reason of grouping? why not just `na.omit(as)` which will be equivalent to `as.dropna()`?? if grouping is indeed needed, which does not make sense as to why, then `as.groupby(["participant","trials"]).dropna()`

Comment: Kindly provide the pandas input dataframe with the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a dataframe (**df**) that looks like this:

```
   participant  trials  Correct_Choice Opt_in
0            1       1             NaN      1
1            1       1             1.0    NaN
2            2       1             NaN      1
3            2       1             0.0    NaN
```

Then you could get the desired output with the following **PYTHON CODE**:

```py
output = df.groupby(['participant', 'trials']).first().reset_index()
print(output)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
   participant  trials  Correct_Choice Opt_in
0            1       1             1.0      1
1            2       1             0.0      1
```